# how to .find() from the actual div in my for

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing a huge file, the following HTML code is only a little part. I have many times the first div. In this div I want to get differents tags in `<a>` I don't care if I also get the element into the `a`.

I'm doing this but It doesn't work :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
page_url = 'https://paris-sportifs.pmu.fr/'
page = requests.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

with open('pmu.html', 'a+')as file:
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_  = 'time_group', attrs={ 'data-time_group' : re.compile("group[1-9]") }):
        event_information = div.find('a', class_ = 'trow--event tc-track-element-events')
        print(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', event_information.text))
```

An exemple of HTML :

```
<div class="time_group" data-time_group="group0">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
             <a class="trow--event tc-track-element-events" href="/event/522788/football/football/maroc-botola-pro-1/rsb-berkane-rapide-oued-zem" data-event_id="rsb_berkane__rapide_oued_zem" data-compet_id="maroc_-_botola_pro_1" data-sport_id="football" data-name="sportif.clic.paris_live.details"       data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Football - Maroc - Botola Pro 1 - RSB Berkane // Rapide Oued Zem - 29 mars 2018 - 19h00">
                <em class="trow--event--name">
             <span>RSB Berkane // Rapide Oued Zem</span>
          </em>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the for loop i get into the different div which interest me but I don't know how I can use this div to do the next : `div.find` I want to do the find in the element on this div not outside (in the soup).

What I except :

```
<a class="trow--event tc-track-element-events" href="/event/522788/football/football/maroc-botola-pro-1/rsb-berkane-rapide-oued-zem" data-event_id="rsb_berkane__rapide_oued_zem" data-compet_id="maroc_-_botola_pro_1" data-sport_id="football" data-name="sportif.clic.paris_live.details"       data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Football - Maroc - Botola Pro 1 - RSB Berkane // Rapide Oued Zem - 29 mars 2018 - 19h00">
                <em class="trow--event--name">
             <span>RSB Berkane // Rapide Oued Zem</span>
          </em>
        </a>
```

Then I just have to find the different tag values in my var.

I hope my english isn't horrible.
Thank you, in advance for your valuable assistance

EDIT 1 :

Let's take an exemple of source code : https://pastebin.com/KZBp9c3y

in this file when i do     `for div in soup.find_all('div', class_  = 'time_group', attrs={ 'data-time_group' : re.compile("group[1-9]") }):` I  find  the first div but imagine we have multiple match in the for loop.

Then I want to find in this div the element with tag `a` and class `trow--event...` `div.find('a', class_ = 'trow--event tc-track-element-events')` 
An exemple of possible result is:

```
data-event_id="brescia__pescara" 
data-compet_id="italie_-_serie_b" 
data-sport_id="football"
score-both :
```

Anyway the problem is that I don't know how to do a  `find` from the div where I am. I'm in `<div class="time_group" data-time_group="group1">` and I want to get different information. I want to parse the div from the top to the bottom.

concretely :

```
for div in soup:
    if current_div is:
        do this.....
    else if:
        do this...
```

**How can I get the `current_div` ?**

Tell me if you don't understand what I want.
Thanks you

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What are you expecting as  the output? Can you add that in the question? As of now, your code is working and is printing all the texts of the `a` tag.

Comment: it's done tell me if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find something it's not exactly what I wanted but it works :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

page_url = 'https://paris-sportifs.pmu.fr/'
page = requests.get(page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

soupdiv = soup.find_all('div', class_  = 'time_group', attrs={ 'data-time_group' : re.compile("group[1-9]") })

for div in soupdiv:
    test = div.find("a", {"class":"trow--event tc-track-element-events"})
    print(test.text)
```

I doing my find from the current div in the for.

thanks you.